# Docker-compose and composer for laravel project

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to use docker ( first time at all ) to build a development env for my laravel projects.

I have read the documentation and looks like that `docker-compose.yml` file is the way to go, at least in my case.

I'm trying to create a LEMP env and this is my compose file:

```
version: "3.1"
services:

    memcached:
      image: memcached:alpine
      container_name: 01dev-memcached

    mysql:
      image: mysql:8.0
      container_name: 01dev-mysql
      working_dir: /application
      volumes:
        - ./:/application
      environment:
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=laravel
        - MYSQL_DATABASE=laravel
        - MYSQL_USER=laravel
        - MYSQL_PASSWORD=laravel
      ports:
        - "8082:3306"

    webserver:
      image: nginx:alpine
      container_name: 01dev-webserver
      working_dir: /application
      volumes:
          - ./:/application
          - ./phpdocker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      ports:
       - "8080:80"

    php-fpm:
      build: phpdocker/php-fpm
      container_name: 01dev-php-fpm
      working_dir: /application
      volumes:
        - ./:/application
        - ./phpdocker/php-fpm/php-ini-overrides.ini:/etc/php/7.3/fpm/conf.d/99-overrides.ini
```

My nginx.conf file:

```
server {
    listen 80 default;

    client_max_body_size 108M;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/application.access.log;


    root /application/public;

    index index.php;

    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^.*$ /index.php last;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass php-fpm:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "error_log=/var/log/nginx/application_php_errors.log";
        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

}
```

since is a Laravel application I need to set the `public` folder as root, so in my nginx.conf I have set it.

If I manually create the `public` folder with a `index.php` with just a `echo "hello";` I'm able to connect and see the string on http://localhost:8080.

Now I need to use composer to install and to manage my project so I found a `composer` image and I have added it under `services` in `docker-compose.yml`:

```
composer:
      restart: 'no'
      container_name: 01dev-composer
      image: "composer"
      command: install
      volumes:
        - ./:/application
```

As far as I know with `volumes` I bind my host to the container path, so it should point outside the `public` folder, am I right?

If I run `docker-compose up` I see that the composer container `exit with code 1`:

```
01dev-composer | Composer could not find a composer.json file in /app
01dev-composer | To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section
01dev-composer exited with code 1
```

And I'm not able to connect to it:

```
docker-compose exec composer install
ERROR: No container found for composer_1
```

How can I use composer in my project? There is a better way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See `composer` [Dockerfile](https://github.com/composer/docker/blob/151ce4cdbd0b1cb8216b7c893dd11833e61c4108/1.8/Dockerfile#L41):

> WORKDIR /app

This image's working dir is `/app`, and also from the [guide](https://hub.docker.com/_/composer), all example mount code directory to the `/app` folder in container.

Besides, the error also tells you that:

> Composer could not find a composer.json file in /app

So, the thing you need to do is mount your code directory to `/app` & make sure this service start first, then it will generate `vendor` folder in your source code directory:

```
volumes:
  - ./:/app
```